# how to avoid dom elements using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom, hide

I can avoid some div elements using conditions, like

```
<% if (true) %>{
<div> </div>
<%}%>
```

can I do this on JavaScript side?

Comment: You write a script which removes the needed element if condition not met.

Comment: JavaScript will take effect after DOM is loaded, so if you want to wait for all element to be loaded and then clean your DOM you use JavaScript, else, you probably want to use a server-side language such as .ASP if I am not wrong for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if/else statement to avoid specific conditions.

```
if (something === true ){
   //target or add specific div
}else {
   //bypass or remove/hide specific div
}
```

JS can't be used inline the way you wish in your example, but if you really need to do inline Div manipulation, you can use PHP if your server supports it. IN the following example, the div id "content" will only be added to the DOM if "somecondition" is met. Otherwise, it remains hidden (not added to the DOM).

```
<body>
    <?php if (somecondition){ ?>
        <div id="content">
           Foo
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
if(true){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ice_frog/g8r9sdba/)